# Left Aligning Multi Column Equations

Tags: align

I'm trying to align multi-column equations to left. But I'm having difficulty with it. For example,

```
\begin{proposition} \textbf{Properties of Fractions}\\
\begin{align*}
    &1.\frac{a}{b}\frac{c}{d} = \frac{ac}{bd} &2.\frac{a}{b}\div\frac{c}{d} = \frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{d}{c}\\
    &3.\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c} = \frac{a+b}{c} &4.\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad+bc}{bd}\\
    &5.\frac{ac}{bc} = \frac{a}{b} &6. \frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}\implies ad = bc
\end{align*}
\end{proposition}
```

But it is rendered like
[image]
I'm using bunch of packages like amsmath, amsthm, etc. How can I align the second column left?

*I've already tried array environment, but it crashes and looks too small. If I should use array, how can I fix this?

Comment: You can use `&&2.` instead of `&2.`and likewise for the other equations in the left column. `align*` alternates between left and right aligned columns which is what you see here. By using `&&` instead of `&` you skip the right aligned column and the following column will be left aligned again.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks! It worked

Answer (score -1):

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
\small {1.}\;& $ \frac{a}{b}\;\frac{c}{d}$ &=& $\frac{ac}{bd}$&&\small{2.} & ${\frac{a}{b}\div{}\frac{c}{d}}$ = $ {\frac{a}{b}}\cdot {\frac{d}{c}}$ \\
\small  {3.}& $\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c}$ & =& $ \frac{a+b}{c}$&  &\small{4.}& $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}$ =\;$ \frac{ad+bc}{bd}$\\
5.&$\frac{ac}{bc}& =& $\frac{a}{b}$& &6.& $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}\implies ad = bc$\\

    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Please try this